# How to calculate charge density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, density, intensity

I am trying to solve this exercise:

> Using this formula calculate electric intensity
> $$
> \vec{E} = \frac{\vec{c}\times \vec{r}}{r^4}
> $$
> $\vec{c}$ is constant vector, $r$ is magnitude of the position vector $\vec{r}$. What is the charge density $\varrho(\vec{r})$ everywhere in  space?

I have already solved electric intensity
$$\operatorname{div}(\vec{E}) = r^{-4} \operatorname{div} (\vec{c} \times\vec{r}) + (\vec{c}\times \vec{r}) \boldsymbol\nabla r^{-4} = -4r^{-6}\vec{r}(\vec{c}\times \vec{r}) = \frac{-4\vec{r}(\vec{c}\times\vec{r})}{r^{6}} $$

However I am not sure how to calculate charge density. Could someone help me/get some hints?

Maybe $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon\mathbf{E}$ ?

Comment: I bet the question simply assumes vacuum where $D = \epsilon_0 E$ as you mentioned, so we can use the maxwell equation in vacuum. From the form of $E$, we can think the electric charge exists in the center of space ($r = 0$).

Comment: What do you mean by $\vec{c}.\vec{r}$?

Comment: Your equation is not consistent.  On the right hand side you have a scalar. So you don't know the electric field vector by this formula.  And you calculate the divergence of a scalar?

Comment: @Urb I have made a mistake. Instead $\cdot$ there should be $\times$. I have already edited my post.

Comment: @nasu I have already edited my post.

Comment: What is your definition of electric intensity? Don't you have $\vec{E}$ already?

Comment: Then just follow the answer already given.  And look again at your mixed product in the last formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *Gauss's law*,

$$\boldsymbol \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

Do you know how to find the charge density from that?

Comment: But he does not have the vector E.

Comment: @nasu He wrote "I have already solved electric intensity" and gave a formula. It may be wrong, I haven't checked. But he is asking how to find charge density, given what he believes to be E.